# Change color of checkbox inside a nested div

Tags: css, sass, background-color

I have a HTML node where the parent has a class "bp3-multi-select-popover". I want to access all checkboxes nested inside this parent and give a background-color of green. The checkboxes will always be inside an li. Please advice. **I do not want to change it generally throughout my app. Only when the checkbox is under .bp3-multi-select-popover class**

[image]

I need to change .bp3-control input:checked ! .bp3-control-indicator with a background of green.

This is what I did to change:

```
.bp3-multi-select-popover
  > div
  > div
  > ul
  > li
  > a
  > div
  > div
  > span.bp3-control
  input:checked
  ~ .bp3-control-indicator {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Please enlighten me on a way to fix this.

This is the link:[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-dew-yjfdn?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the full path which is prone to errors, you can just use the last bit of the selector:

```
.bp3-multi-select-popover .bp3-control input:checked ~ .bp3-control-indicator {
  background-color: green;
}
```

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-benz-7n7zh?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: I want it only if the parent is .bp3-multi-select-popover, not generally.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Updated OP.

Comment: I updated my response, just add it in front of the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.bp3-control input:checked ~ .bp3-control-indicator {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

https://h72uv.csb.app/

Comment: I want it only if the parent is .bp3-multi-select-popover, not generally.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Updated OP.

Comment: @a2441918 check this solution

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
.bp3-multi-select-popover
  .bp3-control
  input:checked
  ~ .bp3-control-indicator {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Thanks.